# SimpleCov rspec and cucumber separately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber

Could you tell me how to setup simplecov to test models with rspec and controller with cucumber only?
I don't like it that rspec and cucumber coverage are mixed together...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SimpleCov.coverage_dir ‘coverage’`

This will allow you to set the directory where the coverage information will go. So one way to configure it will be to put

```
if RUBY_VERSION > "1.9"
  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  SimpleCov.coverage_dir 'coverage/rspec'
end
```

inside of your `test_helper`, and

```
if RUBY_VERSION > "1.9"
  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  SimpleCov.coverage_dir 'coverage/cucumber'
end
```

inside of `features/support/env.rb`

That should separate them. You probably also want to make sure to run the tests separately so that it doesn't merge them.

Comment: In recent versions of simplecov, you shouldn't need the if RUBY_VERSION-wrapping - simplecov should not launch when on 1.8 / JRuby

Comment: And it is required if i start simplecov from .simplecov file?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... no answer.. my solution was to remove the require line from one of the test-frameworks and run the test separately...